# BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast Receiver Not working in Some Phones

Tags: android

Lenovo A 1000 mobile not able to listen to Boot Completed Broadcast receiver.The Same code works on other mobiles perfectly.What might be the reason for that?  Are there any other alternatives to capture Boot Completed event in android other than Broadcast Receivers?

Comment: Several manufacturers include additional settings, permissions, or security features that disallow certain behaviors in third-party apps by default, like running at boot. Look through that device's Settings, or for any apps that are security-related or administrative in nature. I know of at least one app like that on some Lenovos called Security HD.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid them and make them work?

Comment: You mean, is there any way to get around a security feature that the OEM put there specifically to prevent apps from doing certain things without explicit user consent? No, prob'ly not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices (mostly HTC) has a feature called fast reboot which doesn't trigger BOOT_COMPLETED. Instead they trigger QUICKBOOT_POWERON. So you need to register a recever for both broadcasts.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

You can try this one.

Comment: nice.its working fine for me.if its lenovo mobile u should wait atleast 2 minuts then it will open automaticaly.